# counting down showing one result at a time in a div

Tags: javascript, php, css

So I have this snippet of code I made that simply counts down from a number X by subtracting 4 until it cant subtract 4 any more and still get a number greater than or equal to 1.

```
$start = "2647";

for($i = $start; $i >= 1; $i-=4) { 
echo $i . ' '; 
}
```

Now, I need help styling it. Right now it just shoots out a string of numbers separated by a space. Pretty boring.

How can I get one number at a time to display in a `<div>` as it counts down instead of the page of numbers that Ive got now?

Comment: Use Javascript, for example do it clientside and not serverside.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using javascript.

```js
var counter = document.getElementById("counter"),
    value = 2456;

function count(){
  counter.textContent = value;
  value -= 4;
  if (value >= 1) setTimeout(count, 1000);
}
count();
```

```html
<div id="counter"></div>
```

It doesn't really make sense to do this ***live*** counter via the PHP server.